# Empty object while using PHP SOAP to consume WCF SOAP service

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I've got a big problem that I'm fiddling around for several days now :(

Problem is: I need to consume a SOAP service that is provided by some MS WCF server (3rd party server, no access, no debug, no logs, transport secured via https).

WSSE Authentication works like a charme - but every time I send an XML to the server, all data structures are empty. The XML is generated using

new SoapVar( $xml, XSD_ANYXML)

```
 [...]Envelope, Header, Body etc.[...]
     <tem:CreateAccount>
         <tem:c_id>12345</tem:c_id>
         <tem:newAccount>
             <ser:SomeIntegerValue>123</ser:SomeIntegerValue>
             <ser:SomeStringValue1>foo</ser:SomeStringValue1>
             <ser:SomeStringValue2>bar</ser:SomeStringValue2>
             <ser:SomeStringValue3>foofoo</ser:SomeStringValue3>
         </tem:newAccount>
     </tem:CreateAccount>
 [...]
```

c_id is perfectly parsed on WCF server side while everything below newAccount is just empty. I've sniffed the network traffic but I don't see any errors on transport level.

If the XML is directly sent to the server without using PHP SOAP, it works like expected.

Any clue where to check?

Answer (score 0):

https and WSSE Auth have been disabled for testing - now it works like expected.

But re-enabling https and authentification is crucial for the project :(